# iPadOS 14 external keyboard arrow keys issues

Tags: keyboard, ipados

I recently purchased a **Logitech K380** keyboard for my iPad, running iPadOS 14.4. It's awesome, but I have one issue. When I use the arrow keys, it doesn't let me navigate text with the arrow keys. For example, when I enter text on the search bar, I press the arrow key to go back a letter to edit, and it just swipes. Is there a way to change this so I can navigate through text with a hardware keyboard's arrow keys?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: It’s not about the keyboard, it’s about what external keyboard arrow keys do on iPadOS

Comment: It doesn't do this with the built-in iPadOS keyboard or the Apple Magic Keyboard so it's how Logitech is handling the arrow key press on their keyboard.

Comment: The built-in iPadOS keyboard doesn't have arrow keys, but if the Magic Keyboard doesn't do it, you're probably right

Comment: Correct, that's why I was saying it's not an iPadOS thing because it only happens when the Logitech keyboard is attached.

Comment: Have you checked Full Keyboard Access in Accessibility settings?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going to Accessibility > Keyboards > Commands and I disabled the arrow key shortcuts. This allowed the arrow keys to use the default action instead of swiping